# Computing covariance and variance of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> I toss a fair coin three times. Let $X$ denote the number of heads and
>   let $Y$ denote the number of tails.
>
> (a) Find $\text{Cov}(X, Y)$
>
> (b) Find $\rho(X, Y)$

(a) $\text{Cov}(X, Y) = E(XY)-E(X)\cdot E(Y)$

Note that $E(X) = E(Y) = 3/2$.

To compute $E(XY)$, we can just list out all possible products with their probabilities:

$xy = 0$ with probability $1/4$, and $xy = 2$ with probability $3/4$.

Thus, $E(XY) = 0 \cdot \frac{2}{8} + 2 \cdot \frac{3}{4} = 3/2$

$$Cov(X, Y) = 3/2 - (3/2)^2 = -3/4.$$

(b) We need to find $\text{Var}(X)$, which will equal $\text{Var}(Y)$ by symmetry.

$$\text{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2. $$

To compute $E(X^2)$, we have

$$E(X^2) = 1 \cdot \frac{3}{8} + 4 \cdot \frac{3}{8} + 9 \cdot \frac{1}{8} = 3, $$

which means $\text{Var}(X) = 3 - (3/2)^2 = 3/4$. Thus,

$$\rho(X, Y) = \frac{-3/4}{3/4} = -1$$

Comment: Your probabilities in the calculation of $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ are unfortunately not correct. For example, what is the probability of getting exactly two heads in the three coin tosses?

Comment: What's wrong with it ? 3/8

Comment: can you check again? I have made changes @MinusOne-Twelfth

Comment: You subtracted $(3.5)^2$ for the variance, but meant to subtract $(3/2)^2=(1.5)^2$ instead, since $\mathbb{E}[X] = 3/2$. Also, your original value of $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = -3/4$ was the correct one.

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without further calculations it can be deduced that:

$$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,3-X)=-\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)=-\mathsf{Var}(X)$$ and: $$\mathsf{Var}(Y)=\mathsf{Var}(3-X)=\mathsf{Var}(X)$$ so that: $$\rho(X,Y)=\frac{\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(X)}\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}(Y)}}=\frac{-\mathsf{Var}(X)}{\mathsf{Var}(X)}=-1$$

Here $X$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n=3$ and $p=0.5$ so that $$\mathsf{Var}=3\times0.5\times(1-0.5)=\frac34$$

It is a good exercise to verify that with calculation and your result on it is okay now.